# Header on page with chapter heading

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

im writing my thesis in latex and i have a litte problem. How can i also print the header on pages that starts with a chapter heading? On those pages it is missing.

here is a small example of my settings:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper, headings=small]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm,left=40mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{scrhack}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \automark{chapter}
    \ihead{DAS STANDARDISIERTE UNBEWUSSTE}
    \chead{}
    \ohead{\thepage}
    \ifoot*{}
    \cfoot[\thepage]{}

    %Überschriften Apa-konform
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

    \renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}

    \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      beforeskip=.25\baselineskip,
      afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
    ]{chapter}

    \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
      afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
    ]{section}

    \RedeclareSectionCommands[
      afterskip=-1em,
      indent=2em
    ]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}

    \renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
      \hskip #2#3#4.%
    }

    \addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
    \setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize}
    \setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
    \setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\mdseries\itshape}

    \cfoot*{}
    \ofoot*{}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\blindtext \newpage
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

thank you very much
derlu

Comment: Hello! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a _complete_ and _self contained_ example. It means that if we can copy paste the code, it would run _and_ your problem would reveal it self! i.e. it should include a `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really are asking.

Comment: the most of document class which enables division document on chapters deliberately remove headers and footers on chapter first page. you can add them by redesign chapter style. this depends on used document class. since this not known yet, we cant help you. if you use "template" (document class) provided by your university, than don't change desired thesis layout!

Comment: This is considered very bad typographical practice.

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default chapter pages get pagestyle `plain`. With a KOMA-Script class you can change this behavior:

```
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper, headings=small]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm,left=40mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% activates pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{DAS STANDARDISIERTE UNBEWUSSTE}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}

%Überschriften Apa-konform
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.25\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=-1em,
  indent=2em
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}

\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3#4.%
}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\mdseries\itshape}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you can use the starred versions of `\ihead` and `\ohead` to get the same entries for pagestyle `plain`. Then you have to activate the headsepline on plain pages using option `plainheadsepline`:

```
\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% activates pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{DAS STANDARDISIERTE UNBEWUSSTE}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper, headings=small]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=20mm,left=40mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% activates pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{DAS STANDARDISIERTE UNBEWUSSTE}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}

%Überschriften Apa-konform
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.25\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=-1em,
  indent=2em
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}

\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3#4.%
}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\mdseries\itshape}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```